# Angular 2/ Ionic access class function

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Using Ionic (Angular 2) I'm building an app but the following code does not seem te work because I cannot access the function leaveGroup(group) in the Dialog promise.

```
leaveGroupTapped(event, group) {   
 this.dialogs.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this group?", "Confirm")
    .then(function (index) {       
      if (index == 0) {
        //dialog dismissed - do nothing
      } else if (index == 1) {
        //OK call next function to remove the group   
        this.leaveGroup(group) //does not work ofcourse
      } else {
        //Cancel
      }
   });
}

leaveGroup(group) {
//Do some stuff here
}
```

How would you make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem lies in defining the scope of `this.leaveGroup()`.

Modify your code to the following:

```
leaveGroupTapped(event, group) {   
   this.dialogs.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this group?", "Confirm")
     .then((index) => {       
       if (index == 0) {
         //dialog dismissed - do nothing
       } else if (index == 1) {
         //OK call next function to remove the group   
         this.leaveGroup(group) //does not work ofcourse
       } else {
         //Cancel
       }
    });
}
```

Notice here that I used ES6's arrow function here. Now the scope of `this.leaveGroup()` should be defined as such it will work within the scope you are referring to.

`leaveGroup()` should be working alright now.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

For understanding more on how **arrow function**, **this** and **lexical scope** works:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
- https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/

Comment: Yes, had a feeling the scope was messed up but did not know how to fix it. will accept you as answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)